# Azure service bus fails connecting to kubernetes docker

Tags: azure, docker, dockerfile, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub

When I try to access my sb endpoint in my local machine/local docker it fetches the data without any issue but when I try to access it across kubernetes cluster(docker) the connection to socket fails.
Is there any SDK/configs/dependencies that I would have to install in my docker to access the SB. The error looks like below.

```
Found /start.sh, running...
Initializing Client...
[INFO] [2020-07-14 16:00:06] 'eventhub.pysdk-b0fab61b': Created the Event Hub client
[INFO] [2020-07-14 16:00:06] Connection b'bc610657-4dbf-4bc2-aa39-38b6889e6047' state changed from <ConnectionState.UNKNOWN: 999> to <ConnectionState.START: 0>
[INFO] [2020-07-14 16:00:16] b'Failure: select failure.' (b'/data/src/vendor/azure-uamqp-c/deps/azure-c-shared-utility/adapters/socketio_berkeley.c':b'wait_for_connection':370)
[INFO] [2020-07-14 16:00:16] b'wait_for_connection failed' (b'/data/src/vendor/azure-uamqp-c/deps/azure-c-shared-utility/adapters/socketio_berkeley.c':b'socketio_open':770)
[INFO] [2020-07-14 16:00:16] b'Closing tlsio from a state other than TLSIO_STATE_EXT_OPEN or TLSIO_STATE_EXT_ERROR'
[INFO] [2020-07-14 16:00:16] b'Invalid tlsio_state. Expected state is TLSIO_STATE_OPENING_UNDERLYING_IO.' (b'/data/src/vendor/azure-uamqp-c/deps/azure-c-shared-utility/adapters/tlsio_openssl.c':b'on_underlying_io_open_complete':760)
[INFO] [2020-07-14 16:00:16] b'Failed opening the underlying I/O.' (b'/data/src/vendor/azure-uamqp-c/deps/azure-c-shared-utility/adapters/tlsio_openssl.c':b'tlsio_openssl_open':1258)
[INFO] [2020-07-14 16:00:16] b'xio_open failed' (b'/data/src/vendor/azure-uamqp-c/src/saslclientio.c':b'saslclientio_open_async':1097)
[INFO] [2020-07-14 16:00:16] b'Opening the underlying IO failed' (b'/data/src/vendor/azure-uamqp-c/src/connection.c':b'connection_open':1344)
[INFO] [2020-07-14 16:00:16] Connection b'bc610657-4dbf-4bc2-aa39-38b6889e6047' state changed from <ConnectionState.START: 0> to <ConnectionState.END: 13>
[INFO] [2020-07-14 16:00:16] Connection with ID b'bc610657-4dbf-4bc2-aa39-38b6889e6047' unexpectedly in an error state. Closing: False, Error: None
[INFO] [2020-07-14 16:00:16] b'Begin session failed' (b'/data/src/vendor/azure-uamqp-c/src/link.c':b'link_attach':1282)
[INFO] [2020-07-14 16:00:16] b'Link attach failed' (b'/data/src/vendor/azure-uamqp-c/src/message_receiver.c':b'messagereceiver_open':381)
[INFO] [2020-07-14 16:00:16] b'AMQP management instance not open' (b'/data/src/vendor/azure-uamqp-c/src/amqp_management.c':b'amqp_management_close':1029)
[INFO] [2020-07-14 16:00:16] CBS for connection b'bc610657-4dbf-4bc2-aa39-38b6889e6047' completed opening with status: 1
[INFO] [2020-07-14 16:00:16] b'Failed opening message receiver' (b'/data/src/vendor/azure-uamqp-c/src/amqp_management.c':b'amqp_management_open_async':990)
/start.sh complete - exit status_code=1
```

Answer (score 2):

while I can't claim deep familiarity with docker (Am however one of the ServiceBus sdk maintainers for Python) this appears to be in the broad category of "network totally unavailable" error.  I would first make sure that the standard AMQP ports (5671/15671) are open and properly exposed (potentially bidirectionally) for the container+local network.

Apologies if this would be better suited as a comment, karma makes me unable to do so, don't hesitate to shout if this doesn't seem to help.

Comment: @Kibratn Thankyou:) I use http/https which opens up ports for 80/443 so should I get opening AMQP ports as well irrespective of http? Why does it not have problem running in local docker? I'm sorry but I don't understand. Please can you briefly explain?

Comment: Service Bus communicates using the AMQP protocol for most operations, which requires the ports that were mentioned above.  The only HTTP communication that takes place is when using the management operations (create a queue, delete a topic, and similar) which make use of port 443.   Generally speaking, you'll probably want to ensure that your container is exposing ports 5671, 5672, and 443.

Comment: More information on the Service Bus port usage can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-amqp-protocol-guide

Comment: But I dont see that port open for same sb in my local. Just for information how is it just creating connection in local then? @JesseSquire

Comment: Without understanding more context in your local environment, I can't do more than speculate.  For most consumer operating systems, the firewall prevents incoming connections but does not block outgoing connections.  This allows your local machine to open the connection to Service Bus.   I can claim only a passing familiarity with configuring Docker networks, but my understanding is that the port must be exposed to the local host in order for it to be available for bi-directional communication, which is necessary for AMQP.

Comment: The question that I would pose is... did you try exposing the ports in your Docker file and, if so, what was the result?  Doing so is low effort and, in the worst case, you'd prove that it doesn't work and your problem lies elsewhere.